# Build Cordova App (iOS) in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: ios, cordova, azure-devops

I have a Cordova app that I've been developing using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

The app is to run on iOS and Android (at least)

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for my source control and to also build the app.  Additionally, I've hooked VSTS to HockeyApp, with the intention of having a workflow that will allow me to build and then distribute the app to my testers.

The Android build is working fine.

The iOS build is doing my head in.

I think my issue lies with the Signing Certificate and/or the Provisioning Profile.

I have created the signing certificate via my Apple Developer Account.  I then download the cert and imported it into Key Chain Access.  I then exported the cert as a `.p12` file and included it with the application source.

I have also created a provisioning profile, and included the `UUIDs` of my test iOS devices.  This is linked to the above cert, and has also been included with the application source.

In VSTS, I configured the Cordova Extension to allow me to build.

I've configured the "Cordova Build" step to include the cert and provisioning profile:

[image]

However, no matter what I do, my builds are failing with the following error message:

```
2016-05-07T13:00:49.400Z: Cordova version set to 6.0.0 based on the contents of taco.json
2016-05-07T13:00:49.405Z: [command]/usr/local/bin/node /Users/brendan/agent/_work/tasks/CordovaBuild/1.3.8/cordova-task.js
2016-05-07T13:00:49.946Z: [command]/bin/bash /Users/brendan/agent/_work/tasks/CordovaBuild/1.3.8/lib/createkeychain.sh /Users/brendan/agent/_work/2/s/paygle.cordova/_tasktmp.keychain 0.3689059684984386 /Users/brendan/agent/_work/2/s/paygle.cordova/deploy/certificate.p12 ********
2016-05-07T13:00:50.085Z: 1 identity imported.
2016-05-07T13:00:50.156Z:      0 valid identities found
2016-05-07T13:00:50.164Z:     "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
2016-05-07T13:00:50.240Z: Command failed: /usr/bin/security find-identity -v -p codesigning "/Users/brendan/agent/_work/2/s/paygle.cordova/_tasktmp.keychain" | grep -oE '"(.+?)"'
2016-05-07T13:00:50.241Z:
```

I've checked and rechecked the documentation on this, but it's not really clear to me what the issue is.  I suspect that the cert and/or provisioning profile hasn't been created properly, but I'm not sure which bit is wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are another two points you need to know that may cause the signing issue when your build on MAC according to the [instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/apps/secure-certs) on MSDN:

1. Apple's WWDR certificate

> Notice: Apple's WWDR certificate expired on Feb 14th and as a result
>   you may experience signing failures if you have not updated the cert
>   and removed the old one. Follow the steps outlined by Apple under What
>   should I do if Xcode doesn’t recognize my distribution certificate? to
>   resolve the problem. Note that this also affects development certs
>   despite the title.

However, this issue affects the Xcode, but you are using Cordova. So you can check Point 2 first.

2. Build Agent

> Troubleshooting Tip: You should either setup the cross-platform agent
>   as a launch agent (./svc.sh install agent) or run it as an interactive
>   process (node agent/vsoagent.js) when building an Cordova project
>   targeting iOS due to issues with code signing certificate storage when
>   using a launch daemon.

More detailed information about App Signing: [Simple, Secure CI App Signing Using Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/apps/secure-certs)